# How to send big text data from tcp socket to Flutter app?

Tags: sockets, dart, flutter, bigdata

I have a 3000 rows and 20 column data most cell has 50 or 80 character long text. I test using aqueduct and Dart Server to see which one is better intermediate option in between server data and Flutter communication.

I use 2 option for the test. All I can test is that for (var data in _socket) runs about 10 or 12 times to receive whole data. On the other hand _socket.liste lost much of the data.

In both I even use  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7))...
And result was same. In short data they're both very fast. but for big data I am having problem to get correct result.

How to send big text data from tcp socket to Flutter app?

```
  // OPTION 1
  _socket.listen((List<int> data) {
    String _reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
    _reply = "$_reply$_tmpValue";
  });


 // OPTION 2
 await for (var data in _socket) {
    String _reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
    _reply = "$_reply$_tmpValue";
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
  final Socket client = await Socket.connect('192.168.22.120', 3000);
  client.add(utf8.encode('$_requestedData\r\n'));

  client.listen(
          (var data) {
        var ints = new Uint8List.fromList(data).buffer.asInt64List();
        ints.forEach((i) => print('Got $i'));
      },
      onDone: () { print('Done'); client.close(); },
      onError: (e) { print('Got error $e'); client.close(); });

  print('main done');
```

**RESULT**
main done
_reply: 
Got 4206144564389427761
Got 6861850004482897203
Got 2368148215793798714

**UPDATE (Working Solution):**

```
_socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1’, 3000);
_socket.write(_myQuery);


await for (var data in _socket) {
  _reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data);
  _rawValue = _rawValue + _reply;

  int dataLen;
  dataLen = _reply.length;

  int carriageReturnPosition;
  carriageReturnPosition = dataLen - 2;

  int newLinePosition;
  newLinePosition = dataLen - 1;


  // In my scenario it loops 32 times and it takes about 145 seconds to get big data
  if (_reply.substring(carriageReturnPosition, newLinePosition) == '\r' &&
      _reply.substring(newLinePosition, dataLen) == '\n') {
    await _socket.close();
    _returnData = _reply;
  }
}
```

Comment: tried: `_socket.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((data) {
      debugPrint(data);
    }
  );` ?

Comment: try and I got error as FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x4c (at offset 483)

Comment: what encoding is used for sent data?

Comment: _socket.add(utf8.encode('$_requestedData\r\n')); its a utf8

Comment: so how come `utf8.decoder` detects errors? can you use, for testing, `ascii` on both sides?

Comment: I can't test server side but I am guessing its a ISO-8859-9. the my project is on ubuntu and tested as utf8

Comment: also try this var fromByte = new StreamTransformer<List<int>, List<int>>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (data, sink) {
    sink.add(data.buffer.asInt64List());
  }); and getting error about buffer that the getter buffer isnt defined for the classs List<int>

Comment: the server incoming data is ISO-8859-9, but when I send the data to server I use utf8

Comment: I send to server as: _socket.add(utf8.encode('$_requestedData\r\n')); or as _socket.write('$_requestedData\r\n');  and I get data from server. But if the returning result is big I cannot get it as I try to explained in my questions

Comment: I update my question and I get a Uint8List, how to convert to string

Comment: tested and no luck. in short data this prints without error: print("Result: ${new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim()}");
but this, var ints = new Uint8List.fromList(data).buffer.asInt64List(); also prints but has -35 in it. try to convert and I get error because of the negative value

Comment: funny thing is in same machine when I do telnet I get all the data without any error. so is there is a different std telnet and dart:o

Comment: thanks @pskink, I am trying different option now. I will update my question if I can find any solution.

Comment: Hitting the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes I did. First I get modified data. Which is end of the data I get \n and \r. Then in listen data I check if the last 2 character match the \n and \r. Then I close the socket in client side. And work from there. I will post the solution today and hope it will helps you.

Comment: Updated with working part...